# In postman using Javascript how do I fetch value of a key appearing more than once in from an array in response body

Tags: javascript, json, postman

What I am trying to do - parse through JSON response which has an array and from array fetch value of an element which appears more than 1 and save it in environment variable.
Here is the response body for reference -

```
{
"key1": "valueofkey1",
"key2": "valueofkey2",
"arrayname": 
[
{
"arraykey1": "value1",
"arraykey2": "abc",
}, 
{
"arraykey1": "value2",
"arraykey2": "abc",
}
]
}
```

Here is what I am doing -

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("envvarname",data.arrayname[0].arraykey1);
```

It is always saving value1 in environment variable.

looking for a way to save value1 and value 2 under envvarname.

My next question is - Once envvarname has more than 1 value saved, how will the API consuming envvarname be able to execute picking it's value one by one.

Comment: Why not simply create a JS Array and set it as your environment variable? Keep pushing new items into that array and you can use splice to extract each element.

Comment: Thanks @AkshayShenoy - Can you explain what you mean by when you say splice? I was able to solve first part which is to fetch value out of an array in response using -                                                 var appdata = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var len=appdata.array.length;
var envvar_akeyvalue=[];
var j=0;
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    globalvar_akeyvalue[j]=appdata.array[i].arraykey1;
    j=j+1;
}
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("arraykey1", envvar_akeyvalue);

Comment: I assumed that you would want to remove the elements of the array as you read them. For that purpose you would have to use `appdata.array.splice(appdata.array.indexOf('key'), 1)`. If you intend to just read and not delete elements, what you are doing is good

Comment: I would like to keep them, thanks for the tip though. @AkshayShenoy

Comment: After solving part 1 of the question, I have Environment variable saved as arraykey1 with values as value1, value2. Next unsolved mystery is, how to use value1 and value2 one by one as a header in an API call?

Comment: Why don't you use a separating character and construct one string out of all the values and send it as the header. You can retrieve the elements on the server side by splitting the string at every instance of the separating character